# Reducing the menu delay in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Is there any way to reduce or even better remove the menu delay in Google Chrome? I am especially interested in removing those delays in the bookmark menu.

E.g. on Windows we can remove the menu delay of the start menu using [Classic Start](http://www.classicshell.net/):

[image]

I use the latest version of Google Chrome with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I guess no but by editing source. Chrome is barely customizeable at all.

Comment: there are some hidden menus if you type `chrome://chrome-urls/` into the address bar. I don't think you can change that though.